# Embedding and Geo Filter Search in Redis

Tags: redis, vector-database

Does redis support geospatial and vector search like (knn) in the same query. I understand a simple filter query feeding into knn search like the one below would work

```
"(@title:Matrix @year:[2020 2022])=>[KNN 10 @v $B]"
```

I am curious if the filter section can do also do "@location:[long lat radius]". I am hearing this may not be supported but just curious if anyone is aware of a recent change.

Also, if not redis, what other open source vector databases that are easy to setup can do this?

Comment: What source told you it's not supported? I'm interested if there is misleading info out there

Comment: It was one of the older posts. It looks like this support was added in 2.4, if so I am guessing that post was referring an older version.

Comment: there is support to geo polygon search coming in the next stack release to deal with geometries and points

Answer (score 2):

YES.

You can pass any RediSearch command as the filter for the KNN section, as long as it's not including another KNN query.

```
"@location:[long lat radius]=>[KNN 10 @v $B]"
"(<almost anything here>)=>[KNN 10 @v $B]"
```

RediSearch also supports [range queries](https://redis.io/docs/stack/search/reference/vectors/#range-query) on vector fields that you can include in the filter section of the query

```
"@v:[VECTOR_RANGE 0.2 $B1]=>[KNN 10 @v $B2]"
```